# Flash drawing board

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

Is there a drawing board in Flash Professional CS 5.5 installed or an extension? I want to use it to display a text string, and the user would be able to draw above the text. For example I could display a question and the user would be able to circle the right answer. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://flashexplained.com/actionscript/making-an-interactive-drawing-sketchpad/